# What is the purpose of <Directory /> with a local <VirtualHost>

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf, configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does the `<Directory>` tag refer to `/var/www` on the server, or `/`?

What would be the purpose of having a `/` configuration on a VirtualHost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache applies configurations for directories to a request from smallest to largest. In essence the `<Directory />` section specifies virtual host defaults; since every other possible directory will have that portion in its path.

> If multiple (non-regular expression)  sections match the
>   directory (or one of its parents) containing a document, then the
>   directives are applied in the order of shortest match first,
>   interspersed with the directives from the .htaccess files. For
>   example, with

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/home">
  AllowOverride FileInfo 
</Directory>
```

> for access
>   to the document /home/web/dir/doc.html the steps are:
>
> - Apply directive AllowOverride None (disabling .htaccess files).
> - Apply directive AllowOverride FileInfo (for directory /home).
> - Apply any FileInfo directives in /home/.htaccess, /home/web/.htaccess and
>     /home/web/dir/.htaccess in that order.

BTW, in the above example `<Directory /home/web>` would've worked the exact same way. The reason that isn't usually used though is because doing so will make moving your site to a new directory a little more difficult. It's easier to just use `<Directory />` since that will work no matter where the site root is.

There is a full explanation on the Apache site: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory